# IOS APNs notification fail using ad-hoc provisioning profile

Tags: xcode, apple-push-notifications

My application work fine on every device for APNs notification on plug-in using development provisioning profile. When i change to ad-hoc provisioning and upload to testflightapp.com to send to tester for testing, just my own device can registered APNs device token using ad-hoc provisioning profile but the rest of the device cannot register APNs device token. How should i check on this? Any idea?